# How to get access to QPainter 'picture'?

Tags: pyqt5, qpainter

my Python program downloads a photo to `QLabel` using `QPainter.drawPixmap` and after that users become able to draw some shapes (color-filled polygons) on it with mouse. The final task is to calculate area of red-colored polygons:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu6dM.jpg)

I didn't find a better solution than calculate number of pixels of a certain color, but I haven't got a clue how to get access to picture that drawn by QPainter. Could you give me some ideas how to do this?

Comment: Use the same code to [draw it to different paint-device](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/paintsystem.html) (e.g, QImage).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I draw shapes on QImage and after that draw QImage on QLabel.